# How to jump to beginning/end of visual selection

Tags: vim

How can I jump (move the cursor) to the beginning or end of a visual selection?

I looked at `:help motion.txt` but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`o` will take you to the beginning/end of the visual selection, alternating between beginning/end each time you press it.

`:help v_o`
which is within:
`:help visual-mode`

Answer (score 2):

`:help v_o` is not a motion so there is no point looking for it in `:help motion.txt`.

On the other hand, you are in visual mode, so `:help visual-mode` seems to be a more logical resource.